# How does one calculate the voltage/wattage from Seeback Effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermoelectricity

The Seeback Effect is a thermoelectric effect, where two different alloy wires are attached in a loop. One conjunction is heated while the other is cooled, creating a temprature gradient. As the wires have different electic & heat conductivities, one overpowers the other and pushes electrons in a loop.

Heres a diagram that explains how it works:

[image]

***My question: Are there formulas to calculate the voltage and wattage of this effect simply by knowing the two metals, and the min/max temprature?***

Comment: Start with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator and follow links to more specific pages.

Comment: Warning for people coming here to learn about the Seebeck effect : this is not an accurate description of what the Seebeck effect is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know, not just the two metals, but the Seebeck coefficient $S$ of the joint of the two metals. Then your formula is rather simple:

$$V_s=S\Delta T$$

where $V_s$ is the typical notation for the electromotive force (effective voltage) produced by the temperature difference.

If you know not the $S$ of the combined joint but that of each metal, $S_a$ and $S_b$, you would typically simply add them together (with signs). N- and p-type materials will have opposite signs of their Seebeck coefficients, so it actually becomes a subtraction:

$$S=S_a+S_b=|S_a|-|S_b|$$

Comment: Your answer omits the part about the wattage. Essentially, your $V_s$ expression is the open circuit voltage. Once you close the (resistive) circuit, there is also a current and one can calculate the power generated, which is what the OP is asking for. I am too lazy to write up an answer myself, but feel free to improve yours including this step.